# TinyMCE not clickable and editable on dynamically generated textarea

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tinymce, textarea

I have a set of `div` elements for a travel itinerary. I repeat the group of inputs with an add new button. In each group of inputs there is one textarea with TinyMCE.

The initial (parent) textarea is working fine, but the others generated dynamically are not working properly. The TinyMCE textarea is showing but it is completely not clickable, not editable.

I am using this jQuery plugin from GitHub to repeat my div: https://github.com/vurghus-minar/isiaFormRepeater

Here is my div with the set of input fields

```
<div class="isiaFormRepeater repeat-section" id="example" data-field-id="itinerary" data-items-index-array="[1]">

                <div class="col-xs-12 repeat-items">

                    <div class="col-md-12 repeat-item">

                            <div class="row" id="field0">

                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="action_name">Day Travel Plan</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <textarea name="itinerary[1][daydetails]" class="form-control input-md repeat-el"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>



                                <br><br>

                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="action_id">Day No</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input id="itinerary[1][day]" name="itinerary[1][day]" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md repeat-el">

                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <br><br>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="action_json">Remarks</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input type="text" id="itinerary[1][remarks]" name="itinerary[1][remarks]" class="form-control input-md repeat-el">
                                        <div id="action_jsondisplay"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

This is my jQuery code using that plugin documentation.  It successfully repeats the div but TinyMCE is only working on the original div.

```
<script src="../public/js/jquery.min.js">    
<script src="../public/repeater/isia-form-repeater.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#example').isiaFormRepeater({
                    addButton: '<div class="repeat-add-wrapper"><a data-repeat-add-btn class="repeat-add pure-button pure-button-primary" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>Add New City & Hotel</a></div>',
                    removeButton: '<a data-repeat-remove-btn class="repeat-remove pure-button pure-button-primary" href="#">Remove this City</a>'
                });
                $('#example').isiaFormRepeater();

    });


</script>
```

This is my TinyMCE script

```
    <script src="../public/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        height: 200,
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dynamically add additional `textarea` elements to the page you need to run `tinymce.init()` again after each dynamic addition.  I cannot tell from your code if you are doing that but if that is not happening you will get any textarea converted to TinyMCE when the `init()` function is first run but not after that unless you call `init()` again after the elements are part of the DOM.